# Is there a way to convert a javascript object to a string?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a simple chat app and want to greet new users with a welcome mesage, but all i see is [object Object]. The connection is working. What to do?

This is the messages object that i am using to model the messages

```
const generateMessage = (text) => {
    return {
        text,
        createdAt: new Date().getTime()
    }
}

module.exports = {
    generateMessage
}
```

Here is my connection

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("New socket connection")

    socket.emit("message", generateMessage("Welcome to the chat"))
    socket.broadcast.emit("message", "A new user has joined",)

    socket.on("sendMessage", (message, callback) => {
        io.emit("message", message)
        callback()
    })
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        io.emit("message", "A user has left")
    })
})
```

And here is the html where i render the messages to the browser

```
<body>
    Chat app

    <div id="messages"></div>

    <form id="message-form">
        <input name="message" placeholder="Message">
        <button>Send</button>
    </form>
    

    <template id="message-template">
            <p></p>
    </template>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="../chat/chat2.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Where/how do you actually output the object to the page?  Presumably you're trying to output the entire object when you just want its `.text` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay first thing that generateMessage function is not returning proper key value

```
 return {
        text: text,
        createdAt: new Date().getTime()
 }
```

and the second thing you are trying to render the whole object but you should render

```
socket.emit("message", generateMessage("Welcome to the chat").text)
```

Comment: It is returning a proper key value, if you supply a variable to an object it will use the name of the variable as the key and the value of the variable as the value: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/hz3cp9vk/

Comment: @Rohit Kumar Perfect. Now i want to show the time stamp createdAt before the message. How would i do that? I tried  socket.emit("message", generateMessage("Welcome....").text.createdAt

Comment: @Jake.L.B well then you have to store the return object in a variable and then access createdAt same as text. Ex: `let generatedMessage =  generateMessage("Welcome to the chat")`and then `socket.emit("message", generatedMessage.text + ' ' + generatedMessage.createdAt)`

Answer (score 0):

In your client (the html file) you should create the message accessing text property of object:

```
const htmlMessageText = messageObjReceivedFromSocket.text
```

Not pass the object itself.

It'll easier help you if post how you handling the socket events on client.